# How to record exact geolocation?

Tags: php, html, geolocation, ip

I made a script to record certain data from the user that visits the file. However i'd also like to record the exact geolocation of the user.

For example, when you visit http://ctrlq.org/maps/where/ it will ask you permission to see your exact location. I'd like to record this exact location. Could somebody show me how to incorporate this in my script, i do not mind the popup that asks for permission.

```
<?php

$datum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$fh = fopen('logger.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, 'Datum: '."".$datum ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, 'IP Address: '."".$ip ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, 'Hostname: '."".$hostname ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, 'Port Number: '."".$port ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, 'User Agent: '."".$agent ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, 'HTTP Referer: '."".$ref ."<br />");
fwrite($fh, '<hr>'."".$ref ."");
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: Grab the location using javascript `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion();`. Then send this information to your server.

The only other way would be to use an IP lookup service.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: The HTML5 geolocation is running in the client browser. You will need to have a javascript to post the information back to your server for logging purpose.